# Exercise of Algebraic Integers

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Prove that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ isn't an algebraic integer of $\mathbb{Q}$. I have the solution of this exercise, but anyway can i say the following?

Considering the $AKLB$-setup with $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, now $2$ is a square-free integer such that $2\not\equiv 1\;\mathrm{mod}\,4$ so the ring of algebraic integer of the quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is $B=\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$; thus the element $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ cannot be write as $a+b\sqrt{2}$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, and so isn't an algebraic integer of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Can i conclude in this case that in particular $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$ cannot be an algebraic integer of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: It is not an algebraic integer because its minimal polynomial is $X^2-2/9\not \in \Bbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you tell me if what I wrote down is correct?